# Ansible-Ping an IP Address and If unreachable set variable unavailable as true or available as false in ansible

Tags: ansible

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
   - name: 'Ping'
     ping:
```

My task is terminating due to fatal error. I need the task to give me a boolean variable as output i.e. host_available as true or false.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the setting you're after is [`ignore_unreachable: yes`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#task) along with `register: ping_check`

```yaml
- name: attempt to contact {{ inventory_hostname }}
  ping:
  ignore_unreachable: yes
  register: ping_check

- name: set host_available accordingly
  set_fact:
    host_available: '{{ ping_check.unreachable is not defined }}'
```

which works because the task is always successful, but in the case of the unreachable, the `ping_check` has the shape

```json
{"changed": false,
 "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.222.222 port 22: Host is down",
 "skip_reason": "Host 192.168.222.222 is unreachable",
 "unreachable": true}
```

You could also go in the opposite direction of `{{ ping_check.pong is defined }}` but I thought the `.unreachable` check was easier to reason about